# How can I iterate over the vertices of a mesh without an IndexOutOfRangeException?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to draw a gizmo sphere at the location of each vertex in my mesh with the following code:

```
private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        MeshFilter selectedMeshFilter = (MeshFilter)objecttodraw.GetComponent("MeshFilter");
        Mesh mesh = selectedMeshFilter.sharedMesh;
        Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
        Color[] colors = new Color[vertices.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i <= vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            Gizmos.DrawSphere(vertices[i], vertices.Length);
        }
    }
```

I'm getting an exception, "Array index is out of range" on this line:

```
Gizmos.DrawSphere(vertices[i], vertices.Length);
```

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
>
> GetBounds.OnDrawGizmos () (at Assets/Scripts/GetBounds.cs:32)
>
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays in C# are zero-based. That means an array of vertices of length 4 has entries at:

```
0, 1, 2, 3
```

Trying to access an entry at index 4 is asking for the fifth item from a list of four things — so the runtime complains that you're indexing out of the array's bounds.

Your for loop should look like this:

```
for( int i = 0, i < vertices.Length; i++)
```

With a "less than" in the test, not "less than or equal to"